# Securely Storing Password in app.config - information overload

Tags: c#, security, encryption, connection-string, app-config

I have written a console application that connects to an API to download data (using RestSharp). The downloaded data is converted into code first Entity Framework 6 classes by RestSharp and a database is then updated with a `context.SaveChanges` call on the EF6 classes.

The console application will be running as a windows service at the end of the day.

Everything is working fine, but I have been asked by our security guys to make sure that a different system account is used to connect to the API than the one that connects to the database.

The API connection will be made using the account that runs the windows service. That's one user. The Entity Framework connection string is currently set with `UseIntegratedSecurity=true`, and that's the bit that needs to be changed. So.. I thought the best option would be to store the username and password that will connect to the database in the app.config file, but encrypt the values.

Is there a better option than using the app.config file? If there is what is it? If not, could you give a basic example of how to encrypt and decrypt the password in the app.config file that would protect the database? There seem to be downsides to every option (DPAP, SecureString etc.) Should I be using PBKDF2? I'm honestly just getting overwhelmed with options, pros and cons, risks and .net extensions. Is there just one answer that will serve the purpose in an implementable way? Something that is widely accepted as secure that is reasonably easy to put in place?

Maybe I have already read about the best solution, but it has been pulled apart by people who (not meaning this pejoratively) are being pedantic and academic and I turned away from what I should be doing..

*I have read loads of articles and questions about doing this; [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229192/proper-way-to-store-passwords-in-temporary-xml-config-file) say things like "there are many options when it comes to encrypting your data" and then quote lots of third party products, some of them give [detailed examples](https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file) (using the [same suggestion](http://www.dotnetprofessional.com/blog/post/2008/03/03/Encrypt-sections-of-WebConfig-or-AppConfig.aspx) as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204288/connectionstrings-in-app-config-what-about-security)) but seem to get pulled apart in the comments, some give [detailed answers](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15040/standards-for-encrypting-passwords-in-configuration-files) that are very theoretical without helping me to see how to actually do what they say... I'd just really appreciate if someone is able to make a simple suggestion that I can follow!*

Comment: You can encrypt connection string in app.config in a way that it's readable only by windows user it was encrypted for. In your case that will be your windows service user, but does that achieve anything useful in your scenario? Easier to just use intergrated security in this case.

Comment: are you saying that if some nefarious person were to somehow break into the API bit, they wouldn't be able to also connect to the database, if both connections are made with integrated security? If that is the case, I will go back to the security guys and tell them that there is no need for two users...

Comment: The `UseIntegratedSecurity=true` makes the database connection use the credentials of the user account executing it indeed and you need to change it. Here is a sample on [how to use specific credentials with REST API](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=434). IMHO DPAP would be the safest

Comment: @HighPlainsGrifter user1 to execute the service (with access to corporate resources) and user2 to execute the REST API (access to external resources only)

Comment: No, I mean that to satisfy such requirements, as I understood them - you have to run two separate services, under two different users. One to access rest api, and the other to access database, and they communicate via some inter-process communication api (or even via folder, whatever fits your scenario). Encrypting database password won't achieve anything useful, because in any case service user account should be able to decrypt it to use. With only one user - whoever gets access to it - gets access to both database and api in such case.

Comment: Inter-process communication would give no benefit from a security standpoint, that isolation is not enough. It would help managing the password tho, because it would be windows the one that would store the credential of those two separate windows services

Comment: @Evk oh goodness. I see your point; that would make it easier to be secure. I don't relish the amount of work associated with splitting the (basically complete and near the end of the project now) application into two and writing something to send info from one part to the other. Bother.

Comment: As a general advice, those design choices should had been taken at the start of the project, your company should integrate the security guys earlier in the developing process.

Comment: @Cleptus Do you mean that I should be using the current API Key with new credentials, encrypted with DPAP and the windows service should be run by a user that has access to the database, using integrated security in the EF call? Also, not including the security guys earlier is on me, probably. Lesson learnt!

Comment: @Cleptus I'd say inter-process communication can help IF database account has more privileges that what is needed to perform this task, because db access service will only expose necessary functionality via IPC. But then - why not just restrict database account used by a service to only said operations?

Comment: yup, that is indeed my suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all, particularl @Cleptus, whose advice I took, for your advice. In the end, I have taken the API key and encrypted it using DPAP security. This key is essentially the access to the API, so now that is secured I have made a separate user to run the windows service, with access to the database using integrated security.

I now have a long, encrypted value in the app.config file for the api key and the password for the windows service is saved using windows security.